# Strange Wired Mac Keyboard behavior

Tags: keyboard

My wired mac keyboard is acting weird. Some keys perform weird extra insertions. The problem introduced itself when I relogged in after sleep mode and persists since then. The internal MacBook keyboard is not affected. I suspect some corrupted driver settings/files.

I tried the following already, without change:

- login with a different user
- restarting the mac
- dis-/reconnecting the keyboard

Some of the extra insertions happening:

- u => **u[**
- 7 => **7-**
- return => creates a new line and an *****
- m => **m** and a space character
- j => **j'**
- right arrow => performs a **return**

I am on **OS X 10.9.5**

Edit: I plugged the keyboard into a Windows machine, same problem. So it's a hardware issue ... or is it? Is it possible that the keyboard firmware is somehow corrupt? Since many keys are acting strange and not ONE key that's broken.

Can I reset the keyboard firmware?

Comment: What is "Fritz" ?

Comment: *being on the fritz* means *acting weird*, updated the question.

Comment: Thanks :) did you check your keyboard selection is sys pref

Comment: what do you mean with *keyboard selection*? It's active and in use.

Comment: I know that, the question is what keyboard layout is selected in sys pref keyboard? try changing it to US Extended to see.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately changing to US Extended did not help. Changing back to US neither.

Comment: Have another computer you can connect the keyboard to? Might possibly be the keyboard has a fault in it.

Comment: So what keyboard type is it ? it is not the driver but did someone spill stuff on it? did you try the usual mechanical cleaning- blowing ect ?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up carefully removing all the key caps (like shown here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_Cue2IlXIg) and cleaning up the dust/dirt that accumulated over the past two years. I guess it messed with the electronic contacts.